# android soft keyboard can't display when I am using external keyboard scanner

Tags: android

The problem is that if I plug the scanner into the USB port then the soft keyboard never appears.
  can anyone help me ?Thanks very much.

Comment: can you tell me which device it is?

Comment: any scanner activity or all  activity